# What damage spells can wizards use at spell level 1-4 that are not evocation/necromancy/divination?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, damage

In a campaign I am playing, I am a wizard who has had a permanent baleful polymorph effect on me, but I didn't take of Hit Dice. I focus on illusion, and for all the amazing things that illusion can do, it can't do much damage (not count Phantasmal killer). My friend is also a wizard and he specializes in evocation, so I feel that using evocation for damage is an intrusion on his role as the blaster. My opposition schools are divination and necromancy

**What damage spells can wizards use at spell level 1-4 that are not evocation/necromancy/divination?**

I'm looking for 1-4 level spells (not cantrips and only spells that deal direct damage, so not summon monster)

Comment: please don't include self-destructive spells like detonate

Comment: theye are not useful to me

Comment: You should edit those sorts of restrictions on what you're looking for into your question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conjuration has a few good ones. The Acid Splash cantrip does 1d3 damage and has unlimited casts (jk, dont use Acid Splash). Corrosive Touch is 1st level and does decent scaled touch damage. Acid Arrow is 2nd level and also does okay damage.

The level 3 spell Explosive Runes is very damaging, abjuration, and also very situational. At level 4 that same school has Fire Trap, less situational, still kind of tricky.

Burning Disarm is a level 1 transmutation that is not necessarily a direct damage effect, but is still effective. Its drop or take some scaled damage, so not a bad trade for you either way.

You can go [here](http://www.d20pfsrdcompanion.com/spells/wizard-spells) and perform a limited, but useful for your specific purposes, filtered search across spells, and see right in the results list where that spell comes from.

Another thing to consider though is why you are concerned about direct damage spells in the first place. There are so many other valuable roles that a wizard can fill, especially with illusion as his school, that its a bit of a waste to focus on damage. Let the evoker sling bolts of fire and force, and you can be buffing the party and debuffing the enemy. Also focusing on solid crafting is good for both of you. The evoker can make wands with metamagic-enhanced combat spells for you to blast away with (hard to interrupt using a wand when you know the spell) while you can make various trinkets and wondrous items with a wide array of practical and pleasant effect for you and the party. Dont get too caught up with the idea of a wizard as a damage dealer. Its possible, but their real strength lies in their insane ability to buff and control the battlefield when well-prepared.

Comment: I don't want to rely on damage, but in the rounds that I'm doing nothing, I want a damaging option.

Comment: Acid Arrow is a great option, IMO. Burning Disarm is also a good one. Both are relatively low-level spells too, with some damage scaling.